# Infinite loop in path finding

Tags: python, infinite-loop

I want to simulate [body-centered cubic crystal structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_crystal_system) in Python using OpenGL. I have written code to get the `next_nodes`, print if the node satisfies the boundaries and look for next nodes recursively return otherwise.

But the code has some problem its running infinitely. Can anyone help me sort this problem.
Posting the relevant code below (with all the OpenGL calls removed).

```
def get_node(x,y,z,side):
    return [x+side,y,z],[x,y+side,z],[x,y,z+side],[x-side,y,z],[x,y-side,z],[x,y,z-side]

def goto_next_nodes(x,y,z,cube_side,next_nodes,boundary_x,boundary_y,boundary_z):
    for node in next_nodes:
        if 0<=node[0]<=boundary_x and 0<=node[1]<=boundary_y and 0<=node[2]<=boundary_z:
             print node
             x,y,z=node[0],node[1],node[2]
             next_nodes=get_node(x,y,z,cube_side)
             goto_next_nodes(x,y,z,cube_side,next_nodes,boundary_x,boundary_y,boundary_z)
        else:
            return

def display_fcc(cube_side,boundary_x,boundary_y,boundary_z):
     x=y=z=0
     next_nodes=get_node(x,y,z,cube_side)
     goto_next_nodes(x,y,z,cube_side,next_nodes,boundary_x,boundary_y,boundary_z)

display_fcc(5,10,10,10)
```

The recursion starts in `display_fcc` function, `goto_next_node` is the recursive function.

Comment: Please clean up your code.  Remove the bits unrelated to the problem.

Comment: What is the intent of `goto_next_nodes`?

Comment: Well, you know where the problem is (in `goto_next_node`). So try looking in that function whether there's something that could cause a recursion. Like, I dunno, calling the function again on the same arguments? Or trying to find the next node `B` of some node `A` which would turn out to be node `A`? You could use `print` statements to illustrate your `x`,`y,`z`,...

Comment: Why was this question closed? With some allowance for second-language difficulties, the question seems clear enough. The code attempts to implement a depth-first search of a graph of nodes on a face-centred cubic crystal structure, but the search doesn't terminate due to a bug. The OP wanted help finding the bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can memoize your seen nodes, and do not go there for second time, like this code. But I think you need to fix one more thing, the

```
else:
    return
```

is not correct I think, because your for will not iterate any more.

```
def get_node(x, y, z, side):
    return [(x+side,y,z), (x,y+side,z), (x,y,z+side),
            (x-side,y,z), (x,y-side,z), (x,y,z-side)]

seen_nodes = set()

def goto_next_nodes(x, y, z, cube_side, next_nodes, boundary_x, boundary_y, boundary_z):
    for node in next_nodes:
        if node not in seen_nodes:
            seen_nodes.add(node)
            if 0<=node[0]<=boundary_x and 0<=node[1]<=boundary_y and 0<=node[2]<=boundary_z:
                 print node
                 x,y,z=node[0],node[1],node[2]
                 next_nodes=get_node(x,y,z,cube_side)
                 goto_next_nodes(x,y,z,cube_side,next_nodes,boundary_x,boundary_y,boundary_z)
    return

def display_fcc(cube_side,boundary_x,boundary_y,boundary_z):
     x=y=z=0
     next_nodes=get_node(x,y,z,cube_side)
     goto_next_nodes(x,y,z,cube_side,next_nodes,boundary_x,boundary_y,boundary_z)

display_fcc(5,10,10,10)
```

Comment: It would be better to use a set for `seen_nodes` and not a list, so that the membership test is O(1).

Comment: @Gareth Rees Great comment, I had fixed my code, but as an extra hint, It's not O(1) It's O(log n) ;)

Comment: @MostafaR [This page](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) claims it's O(1) average, but O(n) worst case.

Comment: @Gareth Rees Thanks for your answer, I thought that set in python is BST (like set in c++), but looks It's a Hash.

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem, I figured it out by looking the output after I got negative votes :) Thanks :)

Comment: I did it with array first which resulted in missing of some nodes, so I used your code, I'm getting `unhashable type :list` error. I added `seen_nodes.add([0,0,0])` to display_fcc function since I thought seen_nodes might be empty, it work work even then. Plz help

Comment: Lists are not hashable: you need something like `seen_nodes.add(tuple(node))` or better still, represent your nodes as tuples throughout.

Answer (score 4):

Your `next_node` function returns all the nodes that are one step away from `(x,y,z)`, and then in `goto_next_node` you go off to visit all the nodes that are within the boundary. But when you visit a node *you never check to see if you have visited that node before*. So your algorithm gets stuck in a corner and goes round and round, visiting a loop of nodes again and again and again. You can see this clearly if you look at the output:

```
>>> display_fcc(5,10,10,10)
[5, 0, 0]
[10, 0, 0]
[5, 5, 0]
[10, 5, 0]
[5, 10, 0]
[10, 10, 0]
[5, 5, 5]
[10, 5, 5]
[5, 10, 5]
[10, 10, 5]
[5, 5, 10]
[10, 5, 10]
[5, 10, 10]
[10, 10, 10]
[0, 5, 5]  
[5, 5, 5]      # Oops: we've been here before!
[10, 5, 5]
[5, 10, 5]
[10, 10, 5]
[5, 5, 10]
[10, 5, 10]
[5, 10, 10]
[10, 10, 10]
[0, 5, 5]
[5, 5, 5]      # And around we go again.
...
```

So you need to keep track of where you have been, and make sure you don't go there again.

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem, I figured it out by looking the output after I got negative votes :) Anyway MostafaR 's answer is more elaborate, so I voted for it. Thanks :)